# If all $("option:selected") has $(this).val do something

Tags: jquery

I have a group of Selects. I am trying to do something like:

If each `$("option:selected")` has `$(this).val='equal in all'` do something.

But I don't know if I try to put each value in a `var` then compare or do a count.

Maybe should it be something like IF ALL has....

This code works, but can see what to do with it...

It is inside an on change function, so it will alert only when I select

```
$("option:selected").each(function () {
    alert ($(this).val();)
});
```

---

It is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xGRep/).

If both(all) selects is selected if value= Show All, do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('option:selected[value="equal in all"]').length > 0){
  // "equal in all" is selected
}
```

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), then check the `length` property to see how many elements matched that selector.

You can also compare how many values equal "equal in all" versus all elements selected by caching the first selector, then storing a filtered version (and comparing length). e.g.

```
var selectedOptions = $('option:selected'),
    optionsEqualInAll = selectedOptions.filter('[value="equal in all"]');
if (selectedOptions.length == optionsEqualInAll.length){
  // all selected options have the value "equal in all"
}
```

Other than that, the question is a bit vague and maybe if you can be more explicit about what you're going for I can update my answer.

Comment: I updated my question. tried the second option two but without sucess

Comment: @JGSilva: Oops, forgot a reference to `.length` in second example. Give that one a shot now.

Comment: @Brad Christie: for `optionsEqualInAll` you still need `option:selected`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It's more to do with my use of `find` instead of what I should have used: `filter`. I promise it now [officially works](http://jsfiddle.net/fTJge/).

Comment: Tryied [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xGRep/2/) , but without sucess, where am i wrong?

Comment: @JGSilva: What are you after? Are you trying to find out if all `select` elements have "Show All" selected? If so, [this should work](http://jsfiddle.net/xGRep/3/).

Comment: @BradChristie, Exactly! Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to execute some code only if all the selects on the page have a specific value selected.

If that's the case, try this:

```
var $selects = $("select");
$filteredSelects = $selects.filter(function(el){
    return $(el).val() == 'equal in all';
});
if($selects.length == $filteredSelects.length){
    //Do Something
}
```